# Subtraction of two columns on two different models by its ID

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have Two Models

1)Invoice 
2)Recieved Amount

```
class Party:
   party_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Invoice(models.Model):
   party = models.ForeignKey(Party,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   invoice_amount = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

class RecievedAmount(models.Model):
   party = models.ForeignKey(Party,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
   recieved_amount = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

I want to subtract (invoice_amount) from Invoice Model - (recieved_amount) from RecievedAmount Model based on the PartyId (ForignKey)
and return output as [{'party':1,'total_difference':2000},{'party':2,'total_difference':5000}]

total_difference = invoice_amount - recieved_amount

And also parties can be more than 100.

Can you please tell me the query that performs this operation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse
from temp_app.models import Party,Invoice,RecievedAmount
from django.db.models import Sum
# Create your views here.

def getPendingAmount(request):
    parties = Party.objects.all()
    pending_list = []
    for party in parties:
        invoices = Invoice.objects.filter(party=party).aggregate(total_invoice_amount=Sum("invoice_amount"))
        recieved = RecievedAmount.objects.filter(party=party).aggregate(total_recieved_amount=Sum("recieved_amount"))
        if invoices['total_invoice_amount'] is not None and recieved['total_recieved_amount'] is not None:
        
            pending_list.append({"party_name":party.party_name,"invoices_amount":invoices['total_invoice_amount'],"recieved_amount":recieved['total_recieved_amount'],"pendings":invoices['total_invoice_amount']-recieved['total_recieved_amount']})
        elif invoices['total_invoice_amount']:
            pending_list.append({"party_name":party.party_name,"invoices_amount":invoices['total_invoice_amount'],"recieved_amount":0,"pendings":invoices['total_invoice_amount']})
    print(pending_list)
    params = {
        "report":pending_list
    }
    # Pass the params in html file and use like 
    # {% for item in report %}
    # {{item.party_name}}
    # {{item.invoices_amount}}
    # {{item.recieved_amount}}
    # {% endfor %}
    return HttpResponse("Hello")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is in your InvoiceSerializer (considering you have one), you can add a SerializerMethodField called total_difference. And you and add get_total_difference method in your serializer. You can write your logic there.

It could be something like:

```
class InvoiceSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    total_difference = serializer.SerializerMethodField()
    # add your other columns here
    def get_total_difference(self, obj):
       # write your logic here
```

Answer (score 0):

Always try to give related name to Foreign Key fields as it helps you to move from one model to another. Do some changes in the model fields.

**models.py**

```
class Party:
   party_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Invoice(models.Model):
   party = models.ForeignKey(Party,on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="invoice_of_party")
   invoice_amount = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

class RecievedAmount(models.Model):
   party = models.ForeignKey(Party,on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name="recieved_amount_of_party")
   recieved_amount = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

Now for finding difference you can use the following django ORM query using annotate and F expression.

```
Party.objects.annotate(total_difference=F('invoice_of_party__invoice_amount') - F('recieved_amount_of_party__recieved_amount')).values('party_name', 'total_difference')
```

Comment: It returns me like this and how i can show the party name and difference in template

Comment: <QuerySet [<PartyMaster: ABC PVT LTD>, <PartyMaster: DEF PVT LTD>]>

Comment: I have updated the ORM query to show party name and difference.

Answer (score 0):

views :

```
def calc(request):
    total_parties = Party.objects.annotate(
        total_difference=F('invoiced_parties__invoice_amount')-F('amounted_parties__recieved_amount'))
    print(total_parties)
    context = {'total_parties':total_parties}
    return render(request,'your_template.html',context)
```

models:

```
class Party(models.Model):
party_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

def __str__(self):
    return self.party_name

class Invoice(models.Model):
party = models.ForeignKey(Party,on_delete = models.CASCADE,related_name='invoiced_parties')
invoice_amount = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.party.party_name

class RecievedAmount(models.Model):
party = models.ForeignKey(Party,on_delete = models.CASCADE,related_name='amounted_parties')
recieved_amount = models.FloatField(default=0.0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.party.party_name
```

templates:

```
{%for d in total_parties%}
    <p> in the party: {{d.party_name}} the total_difference is {{d.total_difference}}</p><br>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Bro if i not recieved any amount from party then. Now it shows me 0 but the invoice is raised to that party

Comment: Suppose i have raise invoice on ABC but it does not send me any penny then it also wants to show but using the above query it just shows me 0.0 if i not recieved any penny from that party.